# How to check for a text value in a datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I am making a login screen with Visual Basic that will require a number of users to login. I have a Azure database populated with all of my users. I need to check the datagridview/database for the username that they will have entered in a text box.

I have tried several variations of loops and if statements referencing the username column in my database. These were generally For loops that should have the loop continue through the column with no issues.

```
      For i As Integer = 0 To dgvUsers.Rows.Count
        If dgvUsers.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString() = strUsername Then
              frmNavPane.Show()
              Me.Close()

        End If
    Next
```

What should happen is the user should be able to enter their username, it should be checked for in the database. If it exists and is spelled properly etc. it will log the user in to the next form.

Currently it does nothing. I was getting an error for the input string being incorrect until I added .ToString() at the end of .Value. Now even when i click the login button the program does not continue or error.

Comment: `I need to check the datagridview/database for the username`, whats the purpose of the `DataGridView` if a user could type and username they could see? What you need to do is check the database for a user, not something that represents showing data. `Currently it does nothing`, is very broad, the only thing I see above in code is just a loop looking to see if a match is found for a username? Please show all relevant code so we can better assist you.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ is right. I also think, you are doing this the wrong way. Normally some login form is showed first to the user, the user type in account, password and click a button "Login" or similar. You then get the values for account and password, query your database and check if the account and password is found. If yes, you let the user access, else you show an error message.

Comment: It does nothing in the sense that when login is clicked the form does not close nor does it fail at any specific line of code. I was going to use a datagridview because I will need to reference other values from the database. Is there any information on running a query through VB?

Answer (score 0):

Like Çöđěxěŕ said, this check should be done at the database table through a query. Unless you need more information about the user that is stored in the database, a scalar return will suffice. You could also use the username from Environment for the comparison.

```
    Using SqlConn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Con string")
        Using CheckUserCmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table Where UserName=@UserName", SqlConn)
            CheckUserCmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Environment.UserName
            Dim UserInt As Integer = CheckUserCmd.ExecuteScalar
            If UserInt > 0 Then
                'UserExists
            Else
                'UserDoesntExist
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: `Dim UserInt As Integer = CheckUserCmd.ExecuteScalar` will not compile with Option Strict On which it should be. The compiler has no idea what datatype this will be returning. Correct will be `Dim UserInt As Integer = CInt(CheckUserCmd.ExecuteScalar)`